# How to upload multiple photos using facebook php sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, photos

I have tried uploading photos but i could not find a method of uploading multiple photos using php sdk both on user's wall and event or page wall is there any method of uploading more than one photos at a time

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot upload multiple photos using fb php-sdk because

1. Using php you can only add photos using form post which allows you
   to post only one at a time or u need to use zipped files.
2. The sdk doesn't allow zipped file upload so at a time you can post
   only one video or photo using form post.